# ffmpeg: hstack playing one at a time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried this command which merge videos horizontally but 2 videos are playing together at the same time.

```
ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v[1:v]hstack[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2  out.mp4
```

How to make them play one at a time?

Comment: You want black video to play on the top or bottom until the other video ends then switch?

Comment: yes but video is placed side by side. If left video finish, right video will start.